# Trying to combine two VBA programs together

Tags: vba

I have two programs for the same Excel spreadsheet and would like to combine them into one program but I just can't seem to get that to work. If anyone could assist it sure would be appreciated. What I have tried is to take the out the Sub do_it() at the second program and the End Sub out of the first program. I have included everything here so you can see both complete programs.

```
Sub do_it()


    n = [E15]
    Set reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    reg.Pattern = "^[0-9]*\-[0-9]*$"
    reg.Global = True
    For Each cell In      Range("A15:A30,C15:C30,E15:E30,G15:G30,I15:I30")
    strVAL = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    If cell.Value = n And reg.test(strVAL) Then
    Range(“E15”).Value = StrVal
    MsgBox "Found a postivive result in " &   cell.Address
    End If

    Next

End Sub
```

-

```
Sub do_it()

    Dim n, sht As Worksheet, cell As Range, num,          tmp, rngDest As Range

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    n = sht.Range("E15")

    For Each cell In    sht.Range("A15:A30,C15:C30,E15:E30,G15:G30,I15:I3 0").Cells

    tmp = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

    If cell.Value = n And tmp Like "*#-#*" Then

    'get the first number
    num = CLng(Trim(Split(tmp, "-")(0)))
    Debug.Print "Found a positive result in " &    cell.Address

'find the next empty cell in the appropriate row
    Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num,    sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
'make sure not to add before col K
     If rngDest.Column < 12 Then Set rngDest =   sht.Cells(num, 12)

    cell.Offset(0, 1).Copy rngDest
    Exit For

    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Rename the second `Sub` to something else, then just call if from the end of the first one.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used the next answer and it worked but thank-you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you want to do, but to do multiple things it is better to break it down into smaller subroutines or functions, for example, you should do this. To run both you need to call the `sub main`. Remember you cannot have duplicate sub or function names:

```
    Sub main()

        Call FirstCode
        Call SecondCode

    End Sub


    Sub FirstCode()
        n = [E15]
        Set reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        reg.Pattern = "^[0-9]*\-[0-9]*$"
        reg.Global = True
        For Each cell In Range("A15:A30,C15:C30,E15:E30,G15:G30,I15:I30")
        StrVal = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        If cell.Value = n And reg.test(StrVal) Then
        Range(“E15”).Value = StrVal
        MsgBox "Found a postivive result in " & cell.Address
        End If

        Next
    End Sub

    Sub SecondCode()
         Dim n, sht As Worksheet, cell As Range, num, tmp, rngDest As Range

        Set sht = ActiveSheet

        n = sht.Range("E15")

        For Each cell In sht.Range("A15:A30,C15:C30,E15:E30,G15:G30,I15:I3 0").Cells

        tmp = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        If cell.Value = n And tmp Like "*#-#*" Then

        'get the first number
        num = CLng(Trim(Split(tmp, "-")(0)))
        Debug.Print "Found a positive result in " & cell.Address

        'find the next empty cell in the appropriate row
        Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
         'make sure not to add before col K
         If rngDest.Column < 12 Then Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num, 12)

        cell.Offset(0, 1).Copy rngDest
        Exit For

        End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked just like you said!!! I have a lot to learn on this stuff and so it really helps when people like you take the time and provide that assistance. @lbo

Comment: good to hear that! please hit the checkmark (upper left to the answer) to select it as the right answer, also you can upvote it.